# Laravel : How to add particular array store in session

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I am little confused about session as i am new to in laravel. On my laravel app there is a lists of activity, every activity has it's details. When i click on activity button(button name: interesed?) activity id add on session, If i add another activity it is also add on session. I need functionality to add and remove inquiry id from session & on last i want all added activity id.

`Note: I am doing using ajax.`

What i have done sharing here.

`Here is a view of my lists inquiry`

[image]

On my web.php define a route

`Route::get('addInquiryData','Front\PlanController@addInquiry')->name('addInquiryData');`

On view view.blade define onclick function

```
onclick="addInquiry({{ $activity->id }})"
```

On my ajax call

```
 function addInquiry(id) {
        var activity_id = id;
        if(activity_id)
        {
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:"{{ route('addInquiryData') }}?activity_id="+activity_id,
                success:function(res)
                {      
                    if(res)
                    {
                        // operation here
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

On my controller just define a function.

```
 public function addInquiry(Request $request) {
    dd($request->activity_id); // gt activity id here 
}
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Whats the problem?

Comment: I do not know how can i perform this task.So posted here for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this code

> Store Your Activity Id value in variable

```
  $activityId=$request->activity_id
```

> You can add value in session like this

```
if(!Session::has('activity_'.$activityId)){
   session(['activity_'.$activityId=>$activityId]);
 }else{
  session()->forget('activity_'.$activityId);
}
```

> You can remove value in session like this

```
session()->forget('activity_'.$activityId);
```

Comment: You can also check Session::has('Keyname') method

Comment: can you please more specific..if id not on session store it else remove if already exist.

Comment: at last to gt session array `Session::get('activity_')` correct me if m wrong.

Comment: get session array using like this    $input = $request->session()->all();