# Laravel : check if value is available on session or not

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

Just tired to find out how can i search the value from session.I just stored an id to the session.After that if same id requested, need to remove it from session, if id not available add it to the session.

Here is my simple function that added id on session.

```
public function addInquiry(Request $request) {
    Session::push('cart', $request->activity_id);
    return response()->json(Session::get('cart'));
}
```

What am getting on response `["1", "2", "3", "4", "1", "2"]`

How can i check that requested id is already stored in session.

expected result

```
public function addInquiry(Request $request) {
if $request->activity_id is already in session 
   { 
     // remove id from session 
   } else {
     // store in session 
   }
}
return response
```

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
if (in_array($request->activity_id, session('cart'))) {
```

Comment: return an error on first attemp when session null `in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given`

Comment: @Javed well, you've shown `Session::get('cart')` returns an array an not `null`. And `session('cart')` is absolutely the same as `Session::get('cart')`

Comment: `if(in_array($request->activity_id, session('cart'))) {
        $test ="already added";
        return response()->json($test);
        } else {
            Session::push('cart', $request->activity_id);
           return response()->json(Session('cart'));
        }`

Comment: @Javed the code looks fine, but if you still get the error you've mentioned about earlier, this means that `Session::get('cart')` returns `null` and not an array of IDs.

Comment: please reffer. need your help `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48682989/laravel-how-to-add-particular-array-store-in-session/48684086` tired now.