# in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array on response and how to search value on return response

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.5

Two things need to be done

1). When i am adding the `ID` on session array on first time it returns an error that

> "message": "in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given"

2). On return response how can i find that the value is in array or not on.

Here is my function

```
 function addInquiry(id) {
    var activity_id = id;
    if(activity_id)
      {
       $.ajax({
       type:"GET",
       url:"{{ route('addInquiryData') }}?activity_id="+activity_id,
       success:function(res)
         {      
          if(res)
            {
              console.log(res); 
                 /* response on res
                 Activity : Array(3)
                 0 : "1"
                 1 : "2"
                 2 : "3"
                 length : 3 */
            }
         }
        });
      }
     }
```

On my controller define a function to set in session.

```
public function addInquiry(Request $request) {

        $cart = Session::get('cart');
        if(in_array($request->activity_id, $cart)){
            $element = array_search($request->activity_id, $cart);
            unset($cart[$element]);
            Session::put("cart", $cart);
        } else {
            Session::push('cart', $request->activity_id);
        }

    return response()->json(["Activity" => Session::get('cart')]);
}
```

Comment: $cart is null then

Comment: I've answered this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48686062/1227923). Also, since you're using code that I gave you, you should accept the answer and it's always a good idea to upvote too just to say "thank you for your time".

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin oops sorry i thought 've done.check it.+1

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin always waiting for your response!!

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin on `console.log(res); ` gt array..Need to check that the requested id is in array or not.so based on add or remove active class.

Comment: @Javed I'm sorry but I can't help you based on what you've shown. You need to start from debugging it with adding `info(session()->all());` to the `addInquiry()` and looking into the `storage/logs/laravel.log`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your cart object is `null` (`Session::get('cart')` returns nothing). So keep a check for that.

**Try:**

```
if( $cart && in_array($request->activity_id, $cart )) {
```

Comment: Just use `if ($cart ...`, there's no need to *suppress error reporting* with `empty`.

Comment: gt it..and on my script gt response `{"Activity":["1","2"]}`, how can i check that the id is in array or not.

Comment: your syntaxt for `in_array()` is right so whats the issue?

Comment: @SapneshNaik on my php function all is done. On oher side in ajax gt response, check first function, now i want to check that `var activity_id` is available on `res`.how can i do this..tried some code but not succeded.

Comment: @Javed Please post it as another question where even others will be able to help you. It is unwise to extend discussions in the comments